# how can i make a discord bot that tells system status

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to learn how to make a bot that shows the ram usage etc of the virtual server where the bot is running with a command sent from discord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a command like that with [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

Something like this should work (untested):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import psutil

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    bedem = discord.Embed(title = 'System Resource Usage', description = 'See CPU and memory usage of the system.')
    bedem.add_field(name = 'CPU Usage', value = f'{psutil.cpu_percent()}%', inline = False)
    bedem.add_field(name = 'Memory Usage', value = f'{psutil.virtual_memory().percent}%', inline = False)
    bedem.add_field(name = 'Available Memory', value = f'{psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory().total}%', inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = bedem)

bot.run('token')
```

Obviously this is very basic, and there's a lot more you can do with [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), I recommend reading their [documentation](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: tysm <3<3 I added an internet speed test on it, it worked as I wanted.